# THREE.js - Creating a particle system of glowing spheres

Tags: three.js

So I have a simple particle system using THREE.Points and THREE.ParticleBasicMaterial as the material.

All the points are rendered as billboards using this .png image.
[image]

When rendered I expect each particle to be a glowing sphere (not exactly glowing, but definitely having that effect due to the radial gradient fading out into transparency). How to get the transparency to work? The result looks like this:
[image]

My material looks like this (note that I tried using different types of blending modes, but they just make things worse).

```
        this.material = new THREE.ParticleBasicMaterial({
            color: 'transparent',
            size: 0.8,
            map: this.spriteImage,
            transparent: true,
            sizeAttenuation: true
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Add "depthWrite: false" to your material, like this:

```
this.material = new THREE.ParticleBasicMaterial({
    color: 'transparent',
    size: 0.8,
    map: this.spriteImage,
    transparent: true,
    opacity: 0.5,        // should be less than 1.0
    sizeAttenuation: true,
    depthWrite: false
});
```

Comment: Thanks. What does this do?

Comment: When you have an object with transparency over another object with transparency, it results in a glitch like that shown in the image you attached. depthWrite: false  solves that. By the way, you also have to set the opacity of the material, any value less than 1.0. I've updated my answer.

Comment: thanks. I have yet to verify if this works. will mark this as the answer if it works.